# iphone app issue photogallery and user access

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I need to do a simple question i guess...

I know most of you will vote me down, but I'm taking my risk anyways. There are times when google isn't much of a help for me, so here I am.

I need just a simple logic guide on this one. I need to create a database where there are some event names listed, and each event is accessed via a specific password and username.

Once accessed there should be this image gallery, for example :

```
Event 1- Username/Pass- gallery
Event 2- Username/Pass- gallery
Event 3- Username/Pass- gallery
```

Can you please give me the logic on how to continue with this? I started up with a php/mysql script, then I passed to xml, then to json and I'm confused. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that this is a C# question?

Comment: Hi Carsten, i don't know what to use, that's why i asked here...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, the database is remote.

Have a database of event designed.

Then let the user select some event, once he does that, authenticate him/her.

Once authenticated, you need to show images. If they are stored locally, send in the names of images, parse it, and display them. If it is totally remote, send in the urls for the images.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer :)
The database will be online.. because it will be needed to update.. so, yes the logic is how you are saying, but what do you suggest me to use?
I mean, json, xml? the authentication of the user?

Comment: JSON/XML can be your call, whatever you are comfortable with. The authentication can be done in simple way, send the username and password over the http and return the status. Then you can go for different encryption techniques.